# Connecting to MySQL Server JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a MySQL Server using JDBC tool in java (using eclipse). I was just wondering how to enter 2 user/password combinations. The first one is  the one I use to connect to the server(for example when I ssh into the server) and the second one I enter into phpmyadmin. As of now, I am putting in the phpmyadmin password only into the jdbc connection properties and it's not connecting. This is my current statement:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://[IP of server]:3306/[Database Table name]", "[UserName (same as phpmyadmin)]","[Password (same as phpmyadmin)]");
```

I am getting a

```
java.sql.SQLException: null,  message from server: "Host '[My computer's full host name]' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server"
```

I was just wondering if I needed to enter my server login/password (the one I use for ssh) as well in addition to the phpmyadmin username/pwd. I am new to JDBC and MySQL server, so I would appreciate any tips.

Just for background, I am able to connect successfully through ssh and I can login to the server through phpmyadmin.

Comment: Is your MySQL database server running on the same machine as your clients?

Comment: And no, your server login/password doesn't come into play here.  MySQL does its own authentication and authorization.

Comment: It's not running on the same machine that is trying to connect to it, no.

Comment: Okay. Is this "Host not allowed..." a common problem, and do you have any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: With MySQL, you have to set up your accounts to allow access from a given client server (usually mysql for apps that run on the same machine) or specify another server.  This allows you to say you can only access your database from given servers.

Comment: And it's not really a "problem."  It's part of MySQL's security model.  It just takes some understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you log in from PHPMyAdmin, the web server is located on the same server that hosts the Mysql database (in your case). Mysql, by default, does not allow connections from remote hosts; only the local machine may access the database.

I'll take a shot in the dark and say that the computer you're running the java code on is not the same machine that is hosting the mysql server. You must configure Mysql to allow connections from remote hosts via the config file and then change the Host row of the `mysql`.`users` table for the specified user to allow connection from your IP address (or, if security isn't your concern, any IP address.)

To configure mysql to allow connections from remote hosts you must remove the "bind-address=" line from the configuration file.

To allow any host to log on to a specific mysql user, you must set the `mysql`.`users` Host` column to "%".

Both of these must be done.

Comment: Thank You. I will try it as soon as I can and I'll let you know (and then I'll accept the answer as well).

Comment: that is correct. check out http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html. It doesn't specifically say to remove the bind-address= line, but that's what I did when I had this problem and it worked fine.

Comment: @Kgrover Have you solved your problem? If you're having trouble, I can probably help out.

Comment: I was trying to do this through android actually, and I ended up using a web script intermediate after research. However, through plain java your answer solved the problem.

Comment: I am using http://000webhost.com for hosting a database, but I am not able to find any my.ini or my.cnf file.

Answer (score 6):

Here's how you can create an account that can access your server from another client machine:

```
CREATE USER 'bobby'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password';
```

That creates the user, and says he can connect from localhost.

If he is on the machine 192.168.0.5, you'd do something like this:

```
CREATE USER 'bobby'@'192.168.0.5' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_password';
```

Then of course, you have to grant privileges appropriately:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO 'bobby'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename.* TO 'bobby'@'192.168.0.5' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

That's been my experience anyway.

You're probably better off reading [this section on how to specify MySQL accounts](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/account-names.html).

Comment: I cannot try this tonight, but I will tomorrow morning and let you know.

Comment: It takes a few tries (or did for me.)  The single quotes are important and a bit non-intuitive.  And you may have to implement Alex's answer below as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MysqlConnect{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
  Connection conn = null;
  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
  String dbName = "jdbctutorial";
  String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  String userName = "root"; 
  String password = "root";
  try {
  Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+dbName,userName,password);
  System.out.println("Connected to the database");
  conn.close();
  System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
  } catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }
}
```